Constraint that allows multiple rows with the same set of columns?
Is there any way to create a constraint/unique index/filtered index such that there can be multiple rows with the same values as long as they have the same value of another columns?  Specifically in a join table, where the joined tables can have multiple rows as long as another column has the same value for each of these rows?
Something like:
 PK   | R1_id | R2_id | OnlyOneTypeAllowed_id
 --------------------------------------------
 10       1       20        100
 11       1       20        100
 12       1       21        400
 13       2       31        500
 14       2       31        500
 ...

those are valid.  But adding this should fail:
 PK   | R1_id | R2_id | OnlyOneTypeAllowed_id
 --------------------------------------------
 15       1       20         200

Since R1_id and R2_id already exist in the table but have a different value of OnlyOneTypeAllowed_id.
I'm trying to avoid creating another table, view or function, so I'm trying to do a constraint or index.  I have tried to group by the columns and compare the counts, but this isn't working; I'm getting counts of the OnlyOneTypeAllows_id, which doesn't help.
I've used filtered indexes before, but I've used those with specific column values (like status='A', or something), not trying to figure out if there's only one value of a given column (and that column can have multiple values).
My gut tells me that I can't do this withough creating a view or a function, but I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong.
Thanks

You can add functions to check constraints... probably won't be fast but will work.

You can use an indexed view for this but If OnlyOneTypeAllowed_id is functionally dependent on (R1_id,R2_id) then this should be in another table with primary key  (R1_id,R2_id) per normalisation rules

Sounds similar to this recent question, with a couple of trigger-based answers. Both check for consistency with other rows. One throws an error (causing the insert to fail) the other (not recommended) quietly deletes the offending rows.

Here is a db<>fiddle containing an adaptation of the trigger I offered as an answer to the question I referenced above, along with several tests.

Check constraints that call a user-defined function may also work as long as you only need to worry about inserts. For updates, there could be an issue if you attempt to change the monitored values for multiple rows (all rows in a matched group). Because the check constraint is applied row by row, a change to one row may be rejected if it does not match other rows for which pending changes have not yet been applied. This is not an issue if you do not intend to update values after the initial insert.
